# Looping through array and returning Id using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an object with attributes `size` and `item`. And I want to search in the array of objects, if matched it should return the id using underscore.js

For example, `Size=large` and `item= abcd`.

```
`Array=[
object:size=medium item=xyz id=1, 
object:size=Large item=sdf id=2,
object:size=large item=abcd id=3
]`
```

How can i  return or get as id=3

Thanks in advance!!
my question is about objects

Comment: This site isn't a place to have other people do all your work for you for free. You need to work on the code yourself, and then when you hit an issue you can't get passed after research online, then you should ask here.

Comment: check out http://underscorejs.org/#find

Comment: This is a question about underscore..not the work i'm expecting..i'm learning it..

Comment: This is not a duplicate BTW..Don't give any negative comments

Comment: What syntax is your sample data?

Comment: The Underscore documents are very well written and well-organized. I assume you went through them, as you would for any other new library you are learning. Then you would have noticed the `_.findWhere` utility, which does exact what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
//initialize array
a = [{ size: 'medium', item: 'foo', id: 1}, {size: 'large', item: 'foo', id: 2}]

// helper method, if element found it returns its id, null otherwise
function idFinder = function(size, item) {
   var el = _.find(a, function(element) { return (element.size === size) &&    (element.item === item); })
   if (element) {
     return element.id;
   }

   return null;
}

//samples
idFinder("medium", "foo"); // will return 1
idFinder("medium", "bar"); // will return null
idFinder("large", "foo"); // will return 2
```

Comment: Although it's obviously very useful to know about `_.find`, actually there is no need to write all this when we have `_.findWhere`.